# Usb3Vision glass to glass speed

Tags: computer-vision, video-streaming, usb, real-time, usb-camera

anyone know how to reduce usb3.0 camera glass to glass latency to less than 5ms? I measured about 30-70ms of latency, My setup is a 1.6MP 249FPS global shutter usb3.0 camera connect to a Lenovo PC. I am trying to do real time motion calculation, many thanks.

I tried to measure it with the camera pointing a stopwatch on my PC monitor, I tried many different settings still results in a G2G latency 70ms, G2A latency 30ms, the frame rate is 200+fps, but the latency is too high for real time motion. My camera model is HIKROBOT  MV-CA016-10UM.